# How to match brace in console applications for C++

Tags: c++, token

I am making a c++ console app and my issue is that I can not get my braces to match and equal to true when compared to the stack holding the first pair of braces.The method where this algorithm is inserted in has a vector token parameter I have written and rewritten my code several times. In the following post,I am placing a very simple piece of  code to show some idea of what i am trying todo:

stack  deli;

```
for (size_t i=0; i<ie.size(); i++) {        
    if(ie[i].value =="{"|| ie[i].value =="(" || ie[i].value =="[")  

     {deli.push(ie[i].value);

        if(deli.top() != "}" || deli.top() != ")" || deli.top() != "]"){
        return false;
           deli.pop(); 
        }

          if(deli.top() == "}" || deli.top() != ")" || deli.top() != "]"){
              return true;
        }

    }


}//end of for loop
```

Comment: why is your `pop` after a `return`?

Comment: And you don't add closing braces to stack, so they are never going to be in top.

Comment: I am pushing the ie[i].value == "{" on to the stack unless i am doing it incorrectly.

Comment: is there any precedence rule ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is for an assignment?

Here are some tips:

- Separate the cases where you get an open bracket from the ones where you get a closing bracket by using something like if/else if statements
- When you get an open bracket, you want to push it on the stack and that should be it
- When you get a closing bracket, you want to verify the top of the stack to see if there is an associated opening bracket of the **same type (if this is relevant for you)**, and remove that opening bracket by popping the stack.
- When the loop finishes, the stack should be empty, or else there is an error

You probably want this structure:

```
for (size_t i=0; i<ie.size(); i++)
{
    if (/*conditions for open brackets*/) 
    {
        //Push the bracket on the stack
    }
    else if (/*conditions for closing brackets*/)
    {
        //Check the top of the stack if there is an opening bracket
        //If so, pop the stack. If not, error.
    }
}
```

Comment: ,I have tried to do it the way that you have stated by doing the following earlier today,however, it has yet to work properly.     for (size_t i=0; i<ie.size(); i++) {        
        
        if(ie[i].value == "("){
            deli.push(ie[i].value);
        
        
            if(ie[i].value == deli.top()){
                deli.pop();
                return true;
            }
        
        
        
        
        }

Comment: You want to have an "else" in there. Don't put your second if inside the scope of your first if, and check for closing bracket.

Comment: ,How about this: for (size_t i=0; i<ie.size(); i++) {        
        
        if(ie[i].value == "("){
            deli.push(ie[i].value);
        
        }
        if(ie[i].value== ")" && deli.top() =="("){
            deli.pop();
            return true;
        }else if(deli.empty()){
            return false;
        
        }

Answer (score 0):

Logic of your code seems to have some issues. I'm not clear what you are trying to do. Anyway I will help to identify some miss points of your code.

- What is you try to do by condition

`if(deli.top() != "}" || deli.top() != ")" || deli.top() != "]"){`
It looks something wrong to me. **"Not Equal" with "Or"**

- Your code never reaches to below line. because function returns at beofre line.

  `deli.pop();`
- What do you try to do by this condition

  `if(deli.top() == "}" || deli.top() != ")" || deli.top() != "]"){`

It looks something wrong to me **Equl and Not Equl with Or**

If you explain what you need to do by words, Others can help to you

Answer (score 0):

Your code would not work for sure, because you are not matching one type of bracket with other but any type of bracket with any other type.
One of the solution is to count the brace,square bracket, parenthesis as you find them, when their count match they match.
Other solution is more general one, related to compiler construction. If you have studied that subject you you should be able to write a contest free grammer and convert it to Deterministic finite automata(DFA) and then write the program to parse the input. It requries some deep study but really helpful.